# Unfamiliar phrase: ありきたりっちゃありきたり

Tags: phrases

I just came across an unfamiliar phrase: ありきたりっちゃありきたり.

Does anyone know what this means? Mainly its because I don't know what the function of the っちゃ is here.

Comment: Also take a look at this: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21318/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「～～っちゃ」 is a common colloquial pronunciation of 「～～と[言]{い}えば」.  It is heard mainly, if not exclusively, in Kanto.

> 「word or phrase + と言えば + ***same*** word or phrase」 = "somewhat (word/phrase)", "(word/phrase) to a degree", etc.

It is a way of affirming a quality partially, if not entirely.

> 「ありきたりっちゃありきたり」
>
> = "somewhat conventional", "kind of ordinary", "just another ~~", etc.

The best translation would depend on the context.