# How is "あるちゃあるけど" used?

Tags: meaning, usage, set-phrases

As far as I understand "あるちゃあるけど" is close in meaning to "ないとは言い切れない" and "しいていえばある" but I could not find how it is used, nor understand the exact meaning.

Comment: Do you mean しいていえばある?

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21318/9831

Answer (score 3):

Since you haven't provided any context, let me point out that ある could be used in several different ways, like

- stating that something exists (the literal meaning)
- stating that something is reasonable/common/good (cf. それはないよ).

あるちゃあるけど is sometimes used in a longer version

> あるちゃあるけど、ないちゃない

with a loose translation being

> You can't say that it's not a thing, but you can't really say it's a thing either.

(where ある is translated here with the second meaning).

あるちゃあるけど by itself means essentially the same thing:

> あるちゃあるけど
> I guess you *could* say that [but why would you? / but I don't fully agree / ...]

Answer (score 1):

Believe you're missing a letter:

> あるっちゃあるけど

It's an extremely informal way of saying:

> あると言えばあるけど

> I won't deny that we have it

But the underlying connotation is that item is not available for sale/use, or it's reserved for some reason.

-- Starfox