# Does the construct: [verb]+るっちゃ[verb]るけど, make any sense grammatically?

Tags: grammar, kanji, syntax, kana

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2QAVNPdJso&t=2m39s

2年間ぐらい全然漢字使ってなくて、今なんか書こうと思えば、ま、ちょっと難しい。読めるっちゃ読めるけど...
I haven't used kanji at all for about two years, and if I want to write something now, it's a little difficult. I can read it, but ...

I've never heard this っちゃ_るけど construction used before in all my time studying this language. I've searched around but can't find any lessons relating to this on any online grammar guides. Maybe it's rare.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21318/43676

Comment: @aguijonazo  Thanks for the reply, and the link! Since I couldn't find るけど on that post specifically, I'll just assume that っちゃ_るけど = "somewhat ~~", "~~ to a degree", "You could call it ~~, I guess", etc.

Like maybe: 読めるっちゃ読めるけど... = "I can read it somewhat, if you'd like to call it that..."

Answer (score 1):

る is the 終止形 ending of the verb. So as you comment, V +　っちゃ　+ V +　けど would be the general pattern.

- 忙しいっちゃ忙しい (in the post) = I got things to do, but not ultra-busy.
- クラシックを聞くっちゃ聞く = I listen to classical music, but not a huge fan.
- そいつを知ってるっちゃ知ってる = I know that guy, but not very well.

For the meaning, I think you already get it right.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I hope this post will be as useful to future language students as it has been for me.