# What does やあいい exactly mean?

Tags: slang, sentence

> いったい　どんだけ背負やあいいんだか

I'm slightly confused by this やあいい. I can gather from context that he's essentially "How much one must bear?", basically he's complaining that has to bear a heavy burden and the word here is likely 背負い

However, what kind of grammar "やあいい" is exactly

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12525/9831

Comment: That's りゃいい for verbs, so no?

Comment: The word is 背負う is a verb. It corresponds to  the chart, specifically at 言えば→ いいや

Comment: The character at the end is not が but か (question marker).

Answer (score 1):

背負やあ is a contracted form of 背負えば. `eba` can contract into `ya(a)`. If you know 見りゃあ is a slangy version of 見れば, it's the same here.

- [せおう](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%83%8C%E8%B2%A0%E3%81%86): (verb) "to carry on one's back"
- せおえば se-o-**e-ba**: 仮定形 of 背負う
- せおや se-o-**ya**: [eba-to-ya contraction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12525/5010)
- せおやあ: やあ is a variant of や

See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21367/5010