Is 納得っちゃ納得 some kind of expression?
"いやでも。。。納得っちゃ納得だな" the character says this after an unthinkable situation has been resolved. Is some kind of way of saying regard having no choice but to accept a fact?

Possibly related?: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21318/what-is-being-abbreviated-as-%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a1%e3%82%83%e3%81%82-in-%e5%bf%99%e3%81%97%e3%81%84%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a1%e3%82%83%e3%81%82%e5%bf%99%e3%81%97%e3%81%84%e3%81%91%e3%81%a9

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21318/what-is-being-abbreviated-as-%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a1%e3%82%83%e3%81%82-in-%e5%bf%99%e3%81%97%e3%81%84%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a1%e3%82%83%e3%81%82%e5%bf%99%e3%81%97%e3%81%84%e3%81%91%e3%81%a9

@whatyouexpect darn you beat me to it :)
